# Подключение внешних файлов в Typescript

Tags: typescript

Вообщем у меня есть файл allParam.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
   URIApi: 'http://localhost:8090/',
   URIFront: 'http://localhost:4200'
};
```

Представляет из себя статичный объект, мне нужно подключать его в другие ts файлы и использовать там данные строки.Я пробовал сделать так:
Подключаю:

```
import { config } from './../../allParam.config'
```

Использую:

```
...
request.open('POST', config.URIApi + 'api/translates', true);
...
```

И это не работает, я получаю такую ошибку:
Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'URIApi' of undefined

Ну вообщем файл не подключился. Как мне правильно подключить данный файл?

Comment: `import { URIApi, URIFront } from './../../allParam.config'` или `import config from './../../allParam.config'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключить можно так:

```
import * as config from './../../allParam.config'
```